# Why does it say "TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am making a digital clock python program and don't know why it says "TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable" for line:

```
    digital_clock_lbl(1000, update_clock)
```

I watched a yt video, that's where I got the code.
The guy there didn't have a problem, but I do.
I checked the answer of someone else in stack overflow, they said to not name our variable "Label" because there might be an error, however I haven't.

```
import tkinter as ui
import time

window = ui.Tk()

def update_clock():
    hours =  time.strftime("%I")
    minutes = time.strftime("%M")
    seconds = time.strftime("%S")
    am_or_pm = time.strftime("%p")
    time_text = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + am_or_pm
    digital_clock_lbl.config(text = time_text)
    digital_clock_lbl(1000, update_clock)

digital_clock_lbl = ui.Label(window,text="00:00:00",font="Helvetica 72 bold")
digital_clock_lbl.pack()
update_clock()
window.mainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`digital_clock_lbl(1000, update_clock)` doesn't make sense. I guess you were trying to making a live clock, so I think you need
to use `.after` method - `window.after(1000,update_clock)`

Try this -

```
import tkinter as ui
import time

window = ui.Tk()

def update_clock():
    hours =  time.strftime("%I")
    minutes = time.strftime("%M")
    seconds = time.strftime("%S")
    am_or_pm = time.strftime("%p")
    time_text = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + am_or_pm
    digital_clock_lbl.config(text = time_text)
    window.after(1000,update_clock) # Here is the change

digital_clock_lbl = ui.Label(window,text="00:00:00",font="Helvetica 72 bold")
digital_clock_lbl.pack()
update_clock()
window.mainloop()
```

Also, you have a typo in last line - `window.mainLoop` should be lowercase `window.mainloop()`

Comment: Good explanation. One thing you could add tho, is that the error says so because the **label-object** is not a **function** and does not have a **handler-method** for __call__.

Comment: It's not a good answer because it doesn't answer the titular question which is "Why?".

Comment: @martineau At least it helped OP, and BTW someone has already commented on why. I would have added their explanation, but it seemed unneccessary as he can just look at the comment for the explanation.

Comment: `# Here is the change` does not explain why `digital_clock_lbl(1000, update_clock)` generated the error. In other words it doesn't tell the OP (and future readers) why they were doing that would cause such an error — merely how to avoid it. Therefore I don't consider such of a good answer.